# Recursively search and modify complex object (dict of ists of dicts)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a complex object.

Currently it is Dict of Lists of Dicts. But could change in the future while still only using lists and dictionaries.

I would like to find all **list elements** or **dictionary values** with type "datetime" and change them to string.

The recursive search seems to be working but can't figure out how to write the modified value back to the corresponding (dict val or list item).

```
def mod_complex(c_obj):
    if isinstance(c_obj, datetime.datetime):
        print(c_obj)
        c_obj = str(c_obj) ???
    elif isinstance(c_obj, list):
        for v in c_obj:
            mod_complex(v)
    elif isinstance(c_obj, dict):
        for k, v in c_obj.items():
            mod_complex(v)
```

Comment: one way is to return it from every call, the other would be to do the conversion/assignment of string inside the for loops instead of recursing into self again with value to be converted

Answer (score 1):

```
def mod_complex(c_obj):
    if isinstance(c_obj, datetime.datetime):
        print(c_obj)
        return str(c_obj)
    elif isinstance(c_obj, list):
        for i, v in enumerate(c_obj):
            c_obj[i] = mod_complex(v)
    elif isinstance(c_obj, dict):
        for k, v in c_obj.items():
            c_obj[k] = mod_complex(v)

    return c_obj
```

Comment: Good luck with modifying dict while iterating over it.

Comment: @panda-34 as long as it doesn't change sizes, it's fine. This would only ever overwrite existing keys.

Answer (score 1):

You have simple way that consists in returning a new object, each sub-object also being a new one etc.

This look like this:

```py
def mod_complex(c_obj):
    if isinstance(c_obj, int):
        return c_obj*2
    elif isinstance(c_obj, list):
        return [mod_complex(v) for v in c_obj]
    elif isinstance(c_obj, dict):
        return {f"new {k}": mod_complex(v) for k, v in c_obj.items()}

ob = { 
  "1st list": [
    { "A": 1, "B": 2 },
    { "C": 3, "D": 4 },
  ],
  "2nd list": [
    { "E": 5, "F": 6 },
    { "G": 7, "H": 8 },
  ]
}

print(mod_complex(ob))
```

Which prints:

```
{
    "new 1st list": [
        { "new A": 2, "new B": 4 },
        { "new C": 6, "new D": 8 }
    ],
    "new 2nd list": [
        { "new E": 10, "new F": 12 },
        { "new G": 14, "new H": 16 }
    ]
}
```

The advantage of this is that you are sure that nothing will be mutated, and therefore `print(ob)` outputs:

```
{ 
  "1st list": [
    { "A": 1, "B": 2 },
    { "C": 3, "D": 4 },
  ],
  "2nd list": [
    { "E": 5, "F": 6 },
    { "G": 7, "H": 8 },
  ]
}
```